# Collisions Transporters forklift truck

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model where forklifts are moving boxes and storing them, but I am encountering collisions between the forklifts, which is not logical. I have tried using the Transport Control block to avoid collisions, and I have also placed a distance of 4 meters between the forklift and the obstacle, considering the forklift itself as an obstacle, but without success.

Additionally, I have a problem where sometimes, before reaching the storage zone in the StorageSystem, the forklifts need to pass through an additional node with a delay of 20 seconds. As a solution, I have used the "Move by Transporter" block with a delay and then stored it, but this does not work consistently. I also tried adding a release block after the delay and unchecked the release option in the "Move by Transporter" block, but the forklift places the box and waits for another forklift to take it back to storage, whereas I want the same forklift that moved the box to the additional zone to bring it back for storage.

[image]
[image]
[image: my model]

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. First, best only ask 1 question at a time (you can open several issues but focus on 1 question per issue). Second, help us help you: How can we replicate this with a minimum viable model? What is the actual question you have? What have you tried? See some tips to exploit SOF best: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Also, for "how do I do X with AnyLogic", best use the LinkedIn forum instead, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

Comment: i want to have some distance between the forklifts (transporterfleet), I tried to add a minimum distance of 4 meters, and I also checked "recognize all transporters" so that the forklifts consider themselves as obstacles. I added a transport control block and checked "avoid collision," but despite all this, I still have collisions between the forklifts.